# "We cannot locate a server to load the workbook Data Model."

Tags: powerpivot

I get this error when I open powerpivot documents in sharepoint.

> "We cannot locate a server to load the workvbook Data Model."

after I've looked into the logs I came up with this:

> Check Server Version (SQLSERVER2012\POWERPIVOT): Fail (Expected:
>
> > =11.0.2800.0, Actual: 11.0.2100.60).
> >     --> Check Deployment Mode (SQLSERVER2012\POWERPIVOT): Pass.     Monitorable   Check Server Configuration (SQLSERVER2012\POWERPIVOT):
> >     Fail (Uninitialized, ConfigurationError, WrongVersion).     SSPM:
> >     Initialization failed on server SQLSERVER2012\POWERPIVOT:
> >     Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Streaming.ServerConfigurationException:
> >     Server SQLSERVER2012\POWERPIVOT failed configuration checks (Status =
> >     Uninitialized, ConfigurationError, WrongVersion).     at
> >     Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Streaming.OnPremise.Server.AssertServerConfiguration(Server
> >     amoServer, CancellationToken ctx)     at
> >     Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Streaming.OnPremise.Server.Initialize(Guid
> >     serviceId, CancellationToken ctx)     at
> >     Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Streaming.OnPremise.Tasks.InitializationTask.Run(CancellationToken
> >     ctx)

how can I update my analysis server version that doesn't affect anything else?

should I install a CU on my SQL or upgrade it?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I needed to install SQLServer2012SP1-KB2674319-x64-ENU (only the PowerPivot part) in order to increase the version of Analysis Services to 11.0.3000.0