# External Data Refresh failed - Unable to refresh list data in Excel Web Access WebPart

Tags: 2013, excel-services, powerpivot, odata

I have created a PivotChart in Excel workbook that fetches data from a SharePoint list using "OData Data Feed". When refreshing the connection in Excel 2013, the updated data is displayed in PivotChart. But when i upload the same to a SharePoint Library and refresh it through Excel Web Access WebPart, it throws an error.

[image]

After configuring PowerPivot for SharePoint, i am getting a "We cannot locate a server to load the Data Model" error.  
[image]

**Stack Exception**

> SSPM: Initialization failed on server :
>   Microsoft.AnalysisServices.ConnectionException: A connection cannot be
>   made. Ensure that the server is running. --->
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made
>   because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:2383 
>       at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient..ctor(String hostname, Int32 port) 
>       at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.XmlaClient.GetTcpClient(ConnectionInfo
>   connectionInfo)     --- End of inner exception stack trace --- 
>       at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.XmlaClient.GetTcpClient(ConnectionInfo
>   connectionInfo) 
>       at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.XmlaClient.OpenTcpConnection(ConnectionInfo
>   connectionInfo) 
>       at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.XmlaClient.OpenConnection(ConnectionInfo
>   connectionInfo, Boolean& isSessionTokenNeeded) 
>       at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.XmlaClient.Connect(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo, Boolean beginSession) 
>       at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server.Connect(String connectionString, String sessionId, ObjectExpansion expansionType) 
>       at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Streaming.OnPremise.Server.Connect(Nullable`1
>   ctx, Boolean schedulePingTaskOnFailure) 
>       at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Streaming.OnPremise.Server.Initialize(Guid
>   serviceId, CancellationToken ctx) 
>       at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Streaming.OnPremise.Tasks.InitializationTask.Run(CancellationToken
>   ctx)
>
> Check Server Version (ServerName\POWERPIVOT): Fail (Expected:
>
> > =11.0.2800.0, Actual: 11.0.2100.60).
> >         --> Check Deployment Mode (ServerName\POWERPIVOT): Pass.
> >         Monitorable Check Server Configuration (ServerName\POWERPIVOT): Fail (Uninitialized, ConfigurationError, WrongVersion).
> >         SSPM: Initialization failed on server ServerName\POWERPIVOT: Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Streaming.ServerConfigurationException:
> >     Server ServerName\POWERPIVOT failed configuration checks (Status =
> >     Uninitialized, ConfigurationError, WrongVersion).     at
> >     Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Streaming.OnPremise.Server.AssertServerConfiguration(Server
> >     amoServer, CancellationToken ctx)     at
> >     Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Streaming.OnPremise.Server.Initialize(Guid
> >     serviceId, CancellationToken ctx)     at
> >     Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Streaming.OnPremise.Tasks.InitializationTask.Run(CancellationToken
> >     ctx)

Note -
1. SQL Analysis Service(PowerPivot) is in running state.
2. PowerPivot Server has been under Data Model in Excel Service setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue got resolved after [updating the SQL 2012 Server(PowerPivot) version to SP1](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/113589/we-cannot-locate-a-server-to-load-the-workbook-data-model) and changing the account for SQL Server Analysis Services (PowerPivot) to Local System account. Also, the service account used for the Excel Services Application needs to be set as an Analysis Services administrator.

[MSDN reference link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3870.troubleshoot-powerpivot-data-refresh.aspx?Sort=MostUseful&PageIndex=1#Issue_Cannot_Locate_a_server_to_load_a_workbook)